# Rails layout working for root only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm learning to build Rails app, I've written the controller and everything looks fine, then moved to get the views.
As usual I downloaded a template and started to move it into my app (normal html template from [html5up.net](http://html5up.net/)).

All JS files I've put them in `app/assets/javascripts`.

All CSS files I've put them in the `app/assets/stylesheets`.

and in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I've included them all using the `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag`
so everything in theory should be fine.

In my routes file I got those 2 lines:

```
resources :users
root 'users#new'
```

When I start the server and go to the root route `localhost:3000` everything is rendered smoothly and with awesome style, however if I try to access the very same page but from it's original route `localhost:3000/users/new` somewhy the html I get doesn't include images and scripts, and the style is messed up (probably because no images/js), same goes for other pages from the users controller.
I tried putting the js/css files in public folder and linking to them but it gives exact same results.
Any idea what's going wrong and how to fix it?

I'm using Rails 4.2.1

Comment: can you show the link tag for the stylesheet in your layout?

Comment: sure
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'skel' %>`
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>`
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style-xlarge' %>`

Comment: Are you using Chrome or Firefox visiting your pages? If so, can you please post the errors reported by your browser?

Comment: @Aetherus I'm using Firefox, there is no error in the browser, the text is showing, just it doesn't have the style.

Comment: @T.Aoukar Press F12 in your browser to open the developer tools, and refresh your page. Is there any request with response status code 404 or 500?

Comment: @Aetherus yes, there are 404 errors, `style.css` and `style-xlarge.css` from Rails logs I can see this: 
`Started GET "/users/css/style.css"`
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/css/style.css"):`
same for the style-xlarge.css

Comment: Aha! that's the problem. I suppose you're running in env `development`, right? Check `config/environments/development.rb`, does it contain `config.serve_static_files = false`? If so, remove this line or change its value to true.

Comment: There's no such line in the `development.rb` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81256/discussion-between-aetherus-and-t-aoukar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's kinda old, but forgot to post the answer for this.
The problem was in the view html codes, the `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>` was inside a `<noscript>` tags so they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than including each of the stylesheets / javascripts directly, reference them within application.css and application.js respectively. This will add them to the asset pipeline - making the application run faster amongst other things (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

So instead of referencing the scripts directly in application.html.erb, just ensure application.html.erb has these to lines in the head section:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Then check that application.css exists in app/assets/stylesheets and that it includes this line:

```
*= require_tree .
```

This tells it to include every .css file that is within the assets/stylesheets directory (alternatively reference each file individually with a require statement)

Similarly, ensure app/assests/javascripts/application.js includes:

```
//= require require_tree .
```

And that the javascript files are in app/assets/javascripts

Put all the images in app/assets/images

Change all the references to the images in CSS files from

```
url("images/example.png")
```

to

```
url(image_path("example.jpg"))
```

or

```
image-url("example.png")
```

And you should be good to go... the rails helpers should handle the relative path issues that it looks like you've been experiencing.